# how to make tree with tiles style in c# asp html?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, tree

i want to create something like this..

[----------------------------------------------------All---------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[------------------------------------------Standar----------------------------------------------][-------Non Standar--------]
[----------child1----------][------------------------------------child2-------------------------][--child1---][-----child2-----]

if we see above "All" is the root / parent and "Standar" and "Non Standar" are the children and so on..

the node of the child's width will be same as total width of the parent, like "standar" if the width is 75% then the child's width will be same as the total of the parent..

the idea is to create tree like the image above..
the width of each node will be different based on the parent and the child..

but for first I just need how to make tree with tiles style.. for next maybe I can create them by myself

sorry I can't post the image.. I don't have enough reputation..

Comment: Is that a chart your trying to create?

Comment: Looks like a table with cell merged together.

Comment: its like a table yes.. but I would like it to be behave like tree.. so it can expanded and collapsed..

Answer (score 2):

Use d3 charts

http://d3js.org/

d3 has many kind of charting and it is wonderful charting library i ever met

samples:
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion , you should use `GridView` with Multiple Header Rows and merge cell using `HeaderCell.ColumnSpan` .
This example
[Merge Merging GridView Header Columns Multiple Headers ASP.NET](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/11/merging-gridview-headers-to-have.html) will help you !